# Write $\sim$ as a set of ordered pairs, and find the partition of $A$ given by $\sim$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble figuring out part b in this problem:

**Let $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on the set A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, and denote the equivalence class of $x\in A$ by [$x$].**

**Part 1) Suppose that $1 \in [3]$, $4 \in [2]$, and $2 \in [1]$. Prove that $[4] = [3]$.**

**Part 2) Ignore part (a) and suppose now that $\sim$ has 3 equivalence classes. If [1] has 2 elements, [2] has 3 elements, $1\sim6$, $2\sim5$, and $7\sim5$, then:**

1. Write $\sim$ as a set of ordered pairs
2. Find the partition of $A$ induced by $\sim$

I have this as a solution to part 1:
Using Symmetry of equivalent relations:

$1\in[3]\Leftrightarrow 1\sim3$ by symmetry $1\sim3\Leftrightarrow 3\sim1$

$4\in[2]\Leftrightarrow 4\sim2$ by symmetry $4\sim2\Leftrightarrow 2\sim4$

$2\in[1]\Leftrightarrow 2\sim1$ by symmetry $2\sim1\Leftrightarrow 1\sim2$

By transitivity $(3\sim1$ and $1\sim2) \Rightarrow3\sim2$

$(3\sim2$ and $2\sim4) \Rightarrow3\sim4$

$3\sim4\Leftrightarrow4\sim3 \therefore [4]=[3]$

I'm fairly certain part 1 is correct, but I'm confused with part 2.

I'd really appreciate some help with it!

Comment: Where is Part (b)?

Comment: For a start: What are the elements of $[1]$? Well, 1, because $\sim$ is reflexive, and 6, because $1\sim 6$. Since $[1]$ has two elements, that's it. Now find $[2]$, and the third equivalence class must be what's left over.

Comment: @copper.hat I assumed Part 2 was part b. It refers to Part 1 as part a, after all.

Comment: Thanks @CarlHeckman. That's my mistake, the bolded Part 1 was what I answered.  From that though, I have: $[1] = \{ 1, 6 \}$, $[2] = \{2, 5, 7\}$, and $[3] = \{3, 4, 8\}$, which makes sense. Then the set of ordered pairs should be: $\{(1,6), (6,1), (1,1), (6,6), (2,2), (5,5), (7,7), (2,5), (2,7), (5,7),(7,5), (7,2), (5,2), (3,3), (4,4), (8,8), (3,4), (4,3), (3,8), (8,3), (4,8), (8,4)\}$. And the partition set would be $\{\{1,6\}, \{2,5,7\},\{3,4,8\}\}$. Does this look right?

Comment: Yes, it looks right.